# Angular 6 - Render child component as content in parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, fusioncharts

I'm learning Angular and I'm facing an issue too difficult for my actual knowledge.

I'm trying to build a dashboard using Material Angular CDK. Each card inside the dashboard will render a different graph. Here is the issue, the component I'm passing the component as content and it is rendered as string not as component (screenshot). The  folder structure is:

- app-root

  - Header
  - Dashboard

    - GraphType 1
    - GraphType 2
    - ...
    - GraphType n

Below you'll find the code for all the files involved. Let me know if something is missing. Thanks to who will try to help me :)

[image]

---

```
dashboard-rev3.component.html


<div class="grid-container">
      <mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="350px">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
          <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>
                {{card.title}}
                <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
                  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
                  <button mat-menu-item>Move</button>
                  <button mat-menu-item>Edit</button>
                  <button mat-menu-item>Delete</button>
                </mat-menu>
              </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
             {{card.content}}
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </div>


----------


dashboard-rev3.component.ts



  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Breakpoints, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard-rev3',
      templateUrl: './dashboard-rev3.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard-rev3.component.css'],
    })
    export class DashboardRev3Component {

      /** Based on the screen size, switch from standard to one column per row */
      cards = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
        map(({ matches }) => {
          if (matches) {
            return [
              { title: 'Active Contracts', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>' },
              { title: 'Building Trends Bar Graph', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>' },
              { title: 'Rate Clock - Currency PPU', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
              { title: 'Building Trends Bar Graph', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
              { title: 'Hammersmith - consumption analysis - YoY Analysis', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-trend></app-graph-trend>'  }
            ];
          }

          return [
            { title: 'Active Contracts', cols: 5, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
            { title: 'Building Trends Bar Graph', cols: 7, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
            { title: 'Rate Clock - Currency PPU', cols: 4, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
            { title: 'Building Trends Bar Graph', cols: 8, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>'  },
            { title: 'Hammersmith - consumption analysis - YoY Analysis', cols: 12, rows: 1, content: '<app-graph-trend></app-graph-trend>' }

          ];
        })
      );

      constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
    }


----------

graph-bar.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-bar',
  templateUrl: './graph-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph-bar.component.css']
})

export class GraphBarComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: Object;
  constructor() {
      this.dataSource = {
          "chart": {
              "caption": "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
              "subCaption": "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
              "xAxisName": "Country",
              "yAxisName": "Reserves (MMbbl)",
              "numberSuffix": "K",
              "theme": "fusion",

          },
          // Chart Data
          "data": [{
              "label": "Venezuela",
              "value": "290"
          }, {
              "label": "Saudi",
              "value": "260"
          }, {
              "label": "Canada",
              "value": "180"
          }, {
              "label": "Iran",
              "value": "140"
          }, {
              "label": "Russia",
              "value": "115"
          }, {
              "label": "UAE",
              "value": "100"
          }, {
              "label": "US",
              "value": "30"
          }, {
              "label": "China",
              "value": "30"
          }]
      };} // end of this.dataSource
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you rephrase?

Comment: have you tried binding `content` to the `[innerHTML]` property of the container component?

Comment: This is exactly what [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, text content and HTML content are not equal in DOM templates. For security, content is sanitized, so as a result when you try to insert content that contains HTML markup as a string into a template, it is simply rendered as text, not inserted as DOM.

Normally, you would do something like:

```
<mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
     <app-graph-bar></app-graph-bar>
</mat-card-content>
```

to insert another component in the template.

If the inserted component takes content, then it might be something like:

```
<mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
     <app-graph-bar>{{card.content}}</app-graph-bar>
</mat-card-content>
```

If the component needs to be something different depending on content, then you can use template logic:

```
<mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
     <app-graph-bar *ngIf="card.type == 'bar'">{{card.content}}</app-graph-bar>
     <app-graph-pie *ngIf="card.type == 'pie'">{{card.content}}</app-graph-pie>
</mat-card-content>
```

The bottom line is that you can't do what you've tried, but you most likely can do what you want.

As others have mentioned in comments, sometimes you can bind the content to `innerHTML`, but this doesn't always produce the desired result. And if you need more advanced capabilities you can use dynamic component loading.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll study the Dynamic Component Loader and I'll try the solution explained by G. Tranter. 

I'll update you soon :)